# Symfony Form EntityType

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

I'am building a simple product page. Some products could have some extra options (productOptions). These options could be selected due to selectboxes. But the problem is as follows:

I've the following Entities:

**Product**

```
#src/appbundle/entity
<?php
/**
 * Product
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product {

    /**
     * @var string id
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string title
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection|ProductOption[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ProductOption", mappedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $productOptions;
    protected $tempProductOptions;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->productOptions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addProductOption(ProductOption $productOption){
        if($this->productOptions->contains($productOption)){
            return;
        }

        $productOption->setProduct($this);
        $this->productOptions->add($productOption);
    }

    public function removeProductOption(ProductOption $productOption){
        if(!$this->productOptions->contains($productOption)){
            return;
        }

        $productOption->setProduct(null);
        $this->productOptions->removeElement($productOption);
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductOption[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getProductOptions() {
        return $this->productOptions->toArray();
    }

}
```

**ProductOption**

```
#src/appbundle/entity
<?php
/**
 * ProductOption
 */

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Repository\GenusRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductOptionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_option")
 */
class ProductOption {

    /**
     * @var int id
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string title
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var float price
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * ProductOption connected to specific product
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productOptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $price
     */
    public function setPrice($price) {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProduct() {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $product
     */
    public function setProduct($product) {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string)$this->getTitle() . '(&euro;'.$this->getPrice().')';
    }
}
```

This is my ProductType (formbuilder)

```
#src/appbundle/form
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Entity\Product;
use AppBundle\Entity\ProductOption;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'titel'
        ]);

        $builder->add('tempProductOptions', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => ProductOption::class,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
            'choice_attr' => function($productOption, $key, $index) {
                /** @var ProductOption $productOption */
                return [
                    'data-price' => $productOption->getPrice(),
                ];
            },
        ]);

        $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Opslaan'
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class,
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() {
        return 'product';
    }
}
```

**Twig file**
its a very basic example

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test product page</h1>

{{ dump(form) }}

{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.titel) }}
    {{ form_row(form.productOptions) }}
    {{ form_row(form.save) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
</body>
</html>
```

For exmaple product 1 has two options:

- option 1 (50 euro)
- option 2 (60 euro)

In the database option 1 and 2 are connected to product 1
**table product_option**

ID     title    price  product_id

1      option 1 50     1

2      option 2 60     1

But in the view the options are already checked (because they connected through db). Is it possible to uncheck the checkboxes.

**Short version**. Each product could have extra options. These options are stored in db. When creating the form on product page the user could choose for these options, but they are already checked.

Also added the following to my formbuilder

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
    foreach ($view->children['productOptions']->children as $productOption) {
        $productOption->vars['checked'] = false;
    }
}
```

but the checkboxes are still being checked

I've found an solution:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        // arraycollection with productOptions
        $productOptions = $options['data']->getProductOptions();

        $builder->add('id', HiddenType::class, ['mapped' => false]);
        $builder->add('productOptions', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices'  => $productOptions,
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'mapped' => false,
            'choice_value' => function (ProductOption $productOption) {
                return $productOption->getId();
            },
            'choice_label' => function(ProductOption $productOption, $key, $index) {
                return $productOption->__toString();
            },
            'choice_attr' => function(ProductOption $productOption, $key, $index) {
                return [
                    'data-prijs' => $productOption->getPrijs(),
                ];
            },
        ]);
   // rest here ...
```

Comment: Render them in the twig as unchecked

Comment: How could i do that in twig? Because for unchecked i need to remove the checked attribute.

Comment: Could you link your twig file please ?

Comment: @Mcsky I'e edit my first post, and added the twig file. The twig file is very basic.